# Infinite Scroll Without External Content

Tags: jquery, html, css, scroll, infinite-scroll

I am creating a blog in which I want more posts to load when the user scrolls to the bottom of the page. However, I do not want to use a jQuery plugin that pulls the content from another .html file. Instead I want to put all of the posts on one page and limit the amount that are visible then load a couple more as the user keeps scrolling down.

Are There any plugins or snippets that could help me achieve this?

Example:

```
     <-- Visible to users -->
     <article> Pretend this is a preview for an article on a blog</article>
     <article> Pretend this is a preview for an article on a blog</article>
     <article> Pretend this is a preview for an article on a blog</article>
     <-- End of Page -->

     <-- Infinite Scroll Load (Was Hidden Now Visible) -->
     <article> Pretend this is a preview for an article on a blog</article>
     <article> Pretend this is a preview for an article on a blog</article>
     <article> Pretend this is a preview for an article on a blog</article>
     <-- End of Page -->
```

And Repeat So..

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Why? The sole advantage that infinite scroll has over having all the content in the page to begin with is that it means you avoid loading all the content up front. By taking that away, you are making the scrollbar behave weirdly for no benefit.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (pattern)

```
$(function () {
    $("body").css("height", $(document).height() + 1)
        .find("article").each(function (i, el) {
        $(el).not(":nth-last-of-type(n+4)").hide()
            .filter(":nth-of-type(4)").on("click.y", function () {
            $("body").animate({
                scrollTop: "0px"
            }, 1000)
        });
    });
    $(document).on("scroll", {
        "scrolled": false
    }, function (e) {
        if (!e.data.scrolled) {
            var el = $("article:nth-of-type(n+4)");
            $(el).show(1000);
            e.data.scrolled = true;
        };
        if (e.data.scrolled) {
            $(el).on("click", function (e) {
                $(e.target).hide(1000);
            });
        };
        if ($("article:nth-of-type(n+4)").css("display") === "none") {
            e.data.scrolled = false;
        };
        return false
    });
});
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/vTKpP/