# Infinite Scroll - auto load next certain number of posts in background

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, lazy-loading, infinite-scroll

I am developing a wordpress site using infinite scroll. It works fine. But I need to do some modification for visibly faster loading.
When the site is completely loaded, I want to load few more posts to load automatically in background (user will have no idea that more contents are loading). When they reach the bottom of the page (or click on the load more posts button), it then shows those pre-loaded posts, and the system then starts to load few more posts in background again, and so on.
By this way, user will see a lighting fast content load when they reaches the bottom of the page each time.

Any idea how to achieve this please?

Answer (score 0):

Note Not certain about `html` structure, `css`, existing `js` of document, not appear `html` present at original post.

`html` below adapted from [Infinite Scroll Without External Content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23005776/infinite-scroll-without-external-content/23010732#23010732) , perhaps, similar question ?

Try this (pattern)

html

```
<!-- Visible to users -->
<article>Pretend this is a preview (1) for an article on a blog</article>
<article>Pretend this is a preview (2) for an article on a blog</article>
<article>Pretend this is a preview (3) for an article on a blog</article>
<!-- End of Page -->
<!-- Infinite Scroll Load (Was Hidden Now Visible) -->
<article>Pretend this is a preview (4) for an article on a blog</article>
<article>Pretend this is a preview (5) for an article on a blog</article>
<article>Pretend this is a preview (6) for an article on a blog</article>
<button id="articles">Click to view more articles</button>
<!-- End of Page -->
```

js (updated)

```
$(function () {
    $("body").css("height", $(document).height() + 1)
    // `.load()` additional articles
        .find("article").each(function (i, el) {
        $(el).not(":nth-last-of-type(n+4)").hide()
            .filter(":nth-of-type(4)").on("click.y", function () {
            $("body").animate({
                scrollTop: "0px"
            }, 1000)
        });
    });
    $(document).on("scroll.article", {
        "scrolled": false
    }, function (e) {
        if (!e.data.scrolled) {
            var el = $("article:nth-of-type(n+4)");
            $(el).show(1000);
            e.data.scrolled = true;
        };
        if (e.data.scrolled) {
            $(el).on("click", function (e) {
                $(e.target).hide(1000);
            });
        };
        if ($("article:nth-of-type(n+4)").css("display") === "none") {
            e.data.scrolled = false;
        };
        return false
    });

    $("#articles").on("click", $(document), function (e) {
            // `.load()` additional articles
        $(e.target).trigger("scroll.article").scroll()
    })
});
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/bG5N8/

Comment: this is actually not the scenario, i was looking for. however, i have changed the way it should be working and just used infinite scroll, as it is. thanks.